# ActiveRecord SQL queries not getting logged

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, logging

I have been facing a weird problem for some time, wherein ActiveRecord queries are not getting logged in the terminal, or in the Rails console (using `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)`).

This is the exception that I get:

```
Could not log "sql.active_record" event. NameError: undefined 
local variable or method `s' 
for # ActiveSupport::Notifications::Event:0x007f9ae02a60c0.
```

I tried out a few things, including reinstalling Rails, but to no avail.

Apart from wondering why this is happening, I’m unable to check the actual SQL queries fired against the database as a result.

Comment: I've received the same error (`undefined 
local variable or method`) when referencing a variable by the wrong name. ie declare it as `$s` and then try and access as `s`.

Comment: @Akhil: Post entire ruby code here, it will help to debug.

Comment: “undefined local variable or method for ...” means you are calling an unrecognized method on the given object. Somewhere, some code is calling `some_event.s`. It’s unlikely that Rails has a bug like that that hasn’t been caught, so you might have typed `.s` somewhere accidentally. Or maybe the cause is more complicated. I can’t tell where the problem code is without further information. Did the exception give a stack trace with filenames and line numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was due to a stray (and accidental) 's' being inserted in the instrumenter.rb file. Removing the character helped me fix the problem. I'm not sure about why reinstalling rails did not help me though.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into something similar a ways back.

I was able to fix it by adding

```
# config/environments/development.rb
config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

and

```
# config/environment.rb
# To prevent log buffering
$stdout.sync = true
```