# ActiveRecord Sql not getting logged

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a pretty large sized Rails application that has been spitting out

```
Could not log "sql.active_record" event. TypeError: wrong argument type NilClass (must respond to :each) ["/Users/asahmed/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:37:in `zip'",
```

instead of the normal ActiveRecord query used by Rails. This is making development and debugging much more difficult than it needs to be. Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

```
ruby '2.4.2'
gem 'rails', '5.0.7.2'
```

For the record, the solution listed in [ActiveRecord SQL queries not getting logged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865288/activerecord-sql-queries-not-getting-logged) did not solve my problem.

Comment: This seems like some sort of misconfiguration. When did the problem start to occur? Did you upgrade or change any gems?

Comment: It seems like it happened at the start of the year, but since it's a rarely used app I'm not sure exactly when. Do I need to start sifting through old commits to find when the issue started?

Comment: Looks like the issue began around the time we transitioned from Rails 5.0.6 to 5.0.7.2

Answer (score 0):

Check `log` directory of your application. It must contains a `log` file other than `development.log`.

If yes, then check your `application.rb` and `development.rb`. There must be some settings due to which the logs are writing to a different file other than `development.log`.
Search for

```
config.active_record.logger
```

If it is writing to a different file, comment that code and **restart**  the server but don't push these changes to `production`.

Or remove this configuration from `application.rb` and paste in `production.rb`.
In this way, you dont need to repeat this process.

Comment: My log folder contains several other log files, including staging.log, test.log, production.log. The line `config.active_record.logger` doesn't seem to be anywhere in my code base.